# SUMIFS wildcard skips blank cells

Tags: excel, wildcard, formula, excel-2013, sumifs

I am using Excel 2013.  I am setting up a simple data validation dropdown list to allow filtering.  I am running into a weird situation.  Here is a simplified representation of my data:

```
Div      Reg       Amt
========|=========|======
Div1     Reg1      $5
Div2               $10
Div1     Reg2      $8
```

My formula post filter evaluation becomes:

SUMIFS(Amt, Div,"*",Reg,"*")

but the SUMIFS evaluates to $13, not $23.

If I remove the region filter, I get $23.  It seems that SUMIFS is ignoring blank values in the Region column.  How do I fix this?

Comment: I am planning to provide some dropdowns that will filter my data.  The wildcard accounts for the case where the user selects all regions but the user could also select just Reg1, in which case the formula would evaluate to SUMIFS(Amt, Div, "*", Reg, "Reg1")

Comment: Also, my question above was not terribly clear, for which I apologize.  I am using data validation dropdown lists to allow users to select filtering criteria.  I am planning to use the filters as conditions into the SUMIFS formula so that the user can select to see a grand total, or a subtotal for specific division/region combinations of interest to the user.  Hopefully that makes more sense.

Comment: the formula SUMIFS (Amt, Reg, "=") does not give me the expected total.  Also, I have seven different filtering criteria, all of which need to account for the possibility that the user will want to see everything, not just a subset.

Comment: Oh, I get what you're doing.  Yes, that does work, but that would basically mean that I'm adding in all the blank cells to my totals whenever the user filtered by region.  I can use this approach but I was wondering if there was a more elegant answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(Amt,Div,{"*",""},Reg,{"*",""}))
```

Based on [link](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/486427-sumifs-statement.html).
To be more exact you can use `{"*","<>*"}` as a string either equals another one or doesn't.
Implementation is up to you.

Comment: I see where that logic is going but I'm not sure how to modify my formula to fit.  Here's my formula.

=SUMIFS(rangeCurrentSalary,
rangeDivision,INDEX(luDivision,MATCH(filterDivisionRegion,luDivisionRegion,0)),
rangeRegion,INDEX(luRegion,MATCH(filterDivisionRegion,luDivisionRegion,0)),
rangeJobFunction,INDEX(luFunction,MATCH(filterFunctionFamily,luJobFunctionFamily,0)),
rangeJobFamily,INDEX(luFamily,MATCH(filterFunctionFamily,luJobFunctionFamily,0)))


I'm using a lookup to get the conditionals for my sumifs.  It breaks on a "*" wildcard if there are any blanks in the filter range.